# How to return ReportCloud API response into a downloadable file?

Tags: coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion to call the [ReportCloud API](https://docs.reporting.cloud/docs/endpoint/document/merge) which does a mail merge on the fly based on parameters I send it via cfhttp.

The response from the documentation says:

> On success, the HTTP status code in the response header is 200 (OK). The response body contains an array of the created documents encoded as Base64 encoded strings.

Can someone help me with how to turn that response into a downloadable file, either a link or just a straight download? I probably should know this but I don't unfortunately.

**Added comments:**

Thanks for your help and guidance with this question. I'm using StackOverflow as a poster for the first time, my apologies if the question is vague.

I have put together a code example also to view [cffiddle](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=e6a3be97-9f0e-449a-a926-157174e12ee8/721f3b93-4b6f-45d5-87ee-75b6adf934f4/5b2b8e61-5ba6-4927-8df7-96bb7e6eeb90.cfm)

```
<!--- Must replace "Authorization" header below with a real key --->
<cfset variables.jsonReq = '{
    "mergeData": [
        {
            "Given_Name": "Mike",
            "Surname": "Smith",
            "Year_Group": "11"
         },
         {
            "Given_Name": "Sally",
            "Surname": "Smith",
            "Year_Group": "12"
         }
    ],
    "template": null,
    "mergeSettings": null
    }'>

<cfhttp url="https://api.reporting.cloud/v1/document/merge?returnFormat=DOC&templateName=parentletter.docx" method="post" timeout="20" result="response" file="/www/something.docx">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="ReportingCloud-APIKey oMDM4MrAqL9QEOpyzupnQW5NjvCNtvE5cVDaaLqxI">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" name="mergeData" value="#jsonReq#">
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#response#">
```

The response is coming back in what I think is a JSON array. I'm not sure how to go about reading that JSON array and making the contents into a downloadable file.

Comment: Perhaps a combination of a base 64 decoder and the use of `<cffile>`

Comment: Thanks for that. Are you able to provide some examples of how to do that? If you don't mind.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first step is to decode the response and deserialize into the expected array. Dump the raw response and array using writeDump() to verify this is working. Next, use cfhttp to transfer the files to wherever you are going to serve the files. Now that they’re on your file system, provide download links to your user.

Comment: Thanks Redtopia. I understand writedump(). Not so much deserializing the response sorry. Can you provide an example by any chance.

Comment: I've added a bit more information in the description of the request.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  The fiddle isn't working, but it sounds like you need to deserialize the json into a cf array. Then each element should be the file data, encoded as base64. Decode it and do whatever you need - save to a file, download with cfcontent, etc...  Unfortunately you can't do file ops on trycf.com, cffiddle, etc... but this should get you started https://trycf.com/gist/fb846550b4e5b42641e02afc8cfdbaa3/acf2018?theme=monokai

Comment: ... also 1) "result" if you're sending the results to a structure, i.e. `result="response"` then you probably don't want to use the "file"attribute too, i.e. `file="/www/something.docx"` 2) I didn't know if that was a real auth key, so I edited the post to remove it (you should also change it)